# my servlet is not found

Tags: servlets

i'm trying to use a servlet for the first time (and i'm a very bad web developer during my spare time).

I create a servlet and i put it into a folder with all my other classes (javabean). The package where i put my classes is called Jeans.

I made a page that calls the servlet when it is submitted (after pressing a submit button).

```
<form action="prova" method="post" id="FormNews" name="FormNews">
//prova is the name of the servlet
```

I can see that in web.xml there is my servlet

```
   <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>prova</display-name>
    <servlet-name>prova</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>prova</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>prova</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prova</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But  when i trying to see my servlet on a browser i get this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class prova or a class it depends on
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What should i do to use a servlet? Probably i have to set somewhere its path...
Probably TomCat can't see my servlet is in the folder my_web_application_name/jeans

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The package where i put my classes is called Jeans
```

Then your first line of servlet `prova.java`

```
 package jeans; //use small case package name

 public class Prova extends HttpServlet { //see the class name, this is by java naming conventions
 ....
 .......
 }
```

Also, web.xml

```
 <servlet>
  <description></description>
  <display-name>Prova</display-name>
  <servlet-name>Prova</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>jeans.Prova</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Prova</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Prova</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Useful link:**

1. [java-naming-conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)
2. [servlets info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not available in the class path. Ensure its available. If you put in a package, ensure you compile it using package declaration. Once you manually copy the class file , restart the application server. In Web.xml declare the class with package name.

You probably need a tutorial on how to write a servlet.
http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Answer (score 0):

You have to put fully qualified `class` name into `<servlet-class>`

Example :

```
  <servlet-class>examples.servlets.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.
My error was on the "servlet-class" tag.

I wrote 
  `<servlet-class>Prova</servlet-class>`

Instead of

`<servlet-class>jeans.Prova</servlet-class>`

where jeans was the folder where i put my class.